# Include Font-Awesome icons in HAML view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, font-awesome

I am trying to include a Font-Awesome search icon inside the placeholder of a search bar, but I am unable to find a solution or figure it out myself.

So far my code looks something like this:

```
.container.search-customer-container

%input {class: 'form-control customer-search-bar fa fa-search', placeholder: "What are you looking for?"}
  %i.fa-search
```

My gem file: gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 4.5'

I have tried a few different things, but I am new to HAML and struggling a bit.

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: whats your log info?

Answer (score -1):

Use "[font-awesome-rails](https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails)" gem. It's easy to install.

In **gemfile**: `gem "font-awesome-rails"`

in **application.css**:

```
/*
 *= require font-awesome
 */
```

And you are good to go.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I actually didn't go with your answer, I figured out a way to do it by writing it out in .erb and running it through a .haml translator and figuring it out from there using css. I wasn't allowed to add any more gems, but thank you for your help.